# Character with byte sequence 0xd9 0x85 in encoding UTF8 has no equivalent in encoding WIN1252

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Getting the below exception while executing

```sql
select * from function('json obj')
```

one a property of object contains Arabic characters & numbers

like this

```
select * from new_order('


{
    
  "ShippingAddress": "١٠ Test order ", 
}


')
```

if i remove "١٠" everything is OK.

I receive this data from user input, and I can't make any change for mobile app or web site that user is using it to make orders.

The website and mobile app using encoding utf8 and database server is using WIN1252.

Is there any way to avoid this error from function only without change encoding for database server?

Comment: WIN1252 is a Western European character set so there will be no Arabic characters in it to translate to. You will either need to drop the Arabic characters or use some other mechanism to translate them to Western European characters.

Comment: I think you can not to do this because the DB server not accepting such strings in any way.